# Insert <hr> between jquery sortable using AngularJS ng-repeat and ui-sortable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui

I am trying to have `<li>` items sortable using AngularJS ui-sortable within `ng-repeat`. 
So the code look like this:

```
<ul ui-sortable="sortableOption" ng-model="list">
    <li ng-repeat="item in list"> !@#$ </li>
</ul>
```

In between `<li>`s, I want to insert `<hr>` tag so I can have a line border between top and bottom items (after certain numbers of top items). Using an index (ex. if index == 4 insert `<hr>`) doesn't work because the `<hr>` will follow the `<li>` when it's dragging. (It needs to have fixed position while dragging)

Is there any easy way to do this? Right now, I am just calculating each item's height (`<li>`'s height) and put `<hr>` after sum of height from top of the window. (And I can't have separate top and bottom list.)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show visually a little division line, you can use a css for this.

for test, use in your html code:

```
<style>
    ul li { border-top: solid 1px #ddd; padding: 4px 0; }
    ul li:first-child { border-top: 0; }
</style>
```

it has the same effect, but without affect the DOM.